# Can Firebase ML kit be used to detect specific animal faces like only Cats or Dogs from Live Camera?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I need to detect the faces of any animal say Cat and match that to stored photo from database in Android app.

Is this possible to implement through Firebase Face detection APIs OR should I use TensorFlow lite's object detection ?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you can detect an animal's face through the Firebase Face Detection API, because I think it is only suitable for human faces since it allows you to detect features such as facial expression. However, if you want to detect whether there are cats in the frame of your camera, your best bet would be to use the Object Detection API. Additionally, if you train your model well it will be able to detect whether there is a cat's face present in the frame. Once you have your model it is rather straightforward on how to integrate it within your app by using Firebase's ML Kit - for reference you can take a look at their [quick start example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/mlkit).

Answer (score 0):

The ML Kit Image Labeling API should get you what you are looking for. It's available for on-device or cloud processing. The on-device API can distinguish between 400+ labels, including identifying whether there's a cat or a dog in an image. If you are looking for something more specific you can build your own custom model using AutoML Vision Edge in ML Kit, or using TensorFlow Lite directly.